# {TypeError} Object of type Commit is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json

I've a dict with some repo information and I want to write it a json file, but this error raises during dumps method: `{TypeError} Object of type Commit is not JSON serializable`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Cannot run your code. Missing variables repo, ...
Set the needed variables to make your code reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use names/text messages not objects:

```
import git, json

repo = git.Repo('C:/data/foo')
__current_branch = repo.active_branch.name
__tags = repo.tags

SCM_DATA = {
    "CHANGESET": repo.head.commit.message,
    "BRANCH": __current_branch,
    "TAG": __tags[-1].name,
    "IS_DIRTY": repo.is_dirty(),
}

json_version = json.dumps(SCM_DATA)
print(json_version)
```

Out:

```
{'CHANGESET': 'inital commit', 'BRANCH': 'dev', 'TAG': 'v0.0.1', 'IS_DIRTY': True}
```